# Fewest grouped by distinct - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, advanced-search

Ok, I think the answer of this is somewhere but I can't find it...
(and even my title is bad)

To be short, I want to get **the fewest number of group** I can make from a part of an association table

---

*1st, Keep in mind this is already a result of a 5 table (+1k line) join with filter and grouping, that I'll have to run many time on a prod server as powerful as a banana...*

*2nd, This is a fake case that picture you my problem*

---

After some Querying, I've got this data result :

```
+--------------------+
|id_course|id_teacher|
+--------------------+
|    6    |    1     |
|    6    |    4     |
|    6    |    14    |
|   33    |    1     |
|   33    |    4     |
|   34    |    1     |
|   34    |    4     |
|   34    |    10    |
+--------------------+
```

As you can see, I've got 3 courses, witch are teach by up to 3 teacher. I need to attend at one of every course, but I want as few different teacher as possible (I'm shy...).

## My first query

Should answer :  **what is the smallest number of teacher I need to cover every unique course ?**

With this data, it's a `1`, cause Teacher 1 or Teacher 4 make courses for these 3 one.

---

## Second query

Now that I've already get these courses, I want to go to two other courses, the `32` and the `50`, with this schedule :

```
+--------------------+
|id_course|id_teacher|
+--------------------+
|   32    |    1     |
|   32    |    12    |
|   50    |    12    |
+--------------------+
```

My question is : **For id_course N, will I have to get one more teacher ?**

*I want to check course by course, so "check for course 32", no need to check many at the same time*

The best way I think is to count an inner join with a list of teacher of same fewest rank from  the first query, so with our data we got only two : `Teacher(1, 4)`.

For the Course `32`, Teacher2 don't do this one, but as the Teacher1 do `Courses(6, 33, 34, 32)` I don't have to get another teacher.

For the Course `50`, the only teacher to do it is the Teacher12, so I'll not find a match in my choice of teacher, and I'll have to get one more (so two in total with these data)

---

Here is a base [SQLFiddle [image: sqlfiddle]

Best regards, Blag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've finally found a way to do what I want !

For the first query,  as my underlying real need was "is there a single teacher to do everything", I've lower a bit my expectation and go for this one (58 lines on my true case u_u") :

```
SELECT
    (
        SELECT count(s.id_teacher) nb
        FROM t AS m
        INNER JOIN t AS s
            ON m.id_teacher = s.id_teacher
        GROUP BY m.id_course, m.id_teacher
        ORDER BY nb DESC
        LIMIT 1
        ) AS nbMaxBySingleTeacher,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id_course) nb
        FROM t
        ) AS nbTotalCourseToDo
```

[SQLFiddle [image: sqlfiddle]

And I get back two value that answer my question "is one teacher enough ?"

```
+--------------------------------------+
|nbMaxBySingleTeacher|nbTotalCourseToDo|
+--------------------------------------+
|         4          |        5        |
+--------------------------------------+
```

---

The 2nd query use the schedule of new course, and take the id of one I want to check. It should tell me if I need to get one more teacher, or if it's ok with my actual(s) one.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) nb
FROM (
    SELECT
        z.id_teacher
    FROM z
    WHERE
        z.id_course = 50
    ) t1
WHERE
    FIND_IN_SET(t1.id_teacher, (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t2.id_teacher) lst
        FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(s.id_teacher) nb, m.id_teacher
            FROM t AS m
            INNER JOIN t AS s
                ON m.id_teacher = s.id_teacher
            GROUP BY m.id_course, m.id_teacher
            ORDER BY nb DESC
            ) t2
        GROUP BY t2.nb
        ORDER BY nb DESC
        LIMIT 1
        ));
```

[SQLFiddle [image: sqlfiddle]

This tell me the number of teacher that are able to teach the courses I already have AND the new one I want. So if it's over zero, then I don't need a new teacher :

```
+--+
|nb|
+--+
|1 |
+--+
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to get a distinct count of ID_Teachers with the least count then... get a distinct count and limit the results to 1 record.

So perhaps something like...

```
SELECT count(Distinct ID_Teacher), Group_concat(ID_Teacher) as TeachersIDs
FROM  Table
WHERE ID_Course in ('Your List')
ORDER BY count(Distinct ID_Teacher) ASC Limit 1
```

However this will randomly select if a tie exists... so do you want to provide the option to select which group of teachers and classes should ties exist?  Meaning there are multiple paths to fulfill all classes involving the same number of teachers...  For example teachers A, B and A, C fulfill all required classes.... should both records return in the result or is 1 sufficient?

Comment: [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9090a/6) return me `4` and not the `1` I want; I need to get one teacher for every course, and I try to find if there is one teacher that teach every course I need

Comment: it's like solving **"what is the smallest number of teacher I need to cover every unique course ?"**

Comment: Interesting I get it now... still considering.

Comment: Yes, I'm usually not really bad with SQL, but these two are a bit more tricky and I'm stuck on it since 2 day (and as I said, I don't show you the 5 tables Join behind to get this pretty tiny dataset XD) ; I think I have found a way with a sub-Query, grouping and join, but I'll see/test this tomorrow, if I get my brain back...